# Choose which fields to submit in a form

Tags: javascript, python, html, performance, cgi

I am using a hidden form in my python cgi code to pass information on to another cgi file (let's just call it printer.cgi) to print the information in the forms. I have also made clickable text links that all point to the same printer file thanks to this tutorial:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/textsubmit.shtml

The hidden form contains a massive, nested dictionary that has been encoded into text with JSON. The printer file then turns that string back into a dictionary object. Based on which link was clicked, the printer file decides what information in the dictionary to print. However, decoding and encoding the entire dictionary is inefficient and really slows down my program. Instead I would like to submit through the hidden form smaller dictonary objects to print rather than the entire dictionary. Here is an example of what I am currently doing:

JavaScript code:

```
function getDetails(selectedField) 
        {
            document.Results.resultsToPrint.value = selectedField;
            document.Results.submit();
        }
```

Python method:

```
def transferTestResults(testResults, PRINTER_FILE_DIRECTORY):
        form = "<form name = 'Results' method = 'post' action = '%s'> \n" % (PRINTER_FILE_DIRECTORY)
        dataString = str(json.dumps(testResults)) #converting massive dictionary into string
        dataString = dataString.replace("\"", "&quot;")
        form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'testResults' value = \"%s\">" % (dataString) 
        form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'resultsToPrint' > \n"#value is determined by javascript:getDetails()
        form += "</form> \n"
        return form
```

testResults here is the one big dictionary. Instead I would rather make a form for each nested dictionary such as:

```
def transferTestResults(testResults, DETAIL_GENERATOR_DIRECTORY):
    form = "<form name = 'Results' method = 'post' action = '%s'> \n" % (DETAIL_GENERATOR_DIRECTORY)
    dataString1 = str(json.dumps(testResults['testPasses']))
    dataString1 = dataString.replace("\"", "&quot;")
    dataString2 = str(json.dumps(testResults['testFailures']))
    dataString2 = dataString.replace("\"", "&quot;")
    dataString3 = str(json.dumps(testResults['commandPasses']))
    dataString3 = dataString.replace("\"", "&quot;")
    dataString4 = str(json.dumps(testResults['commandFailures']))
    dataString4 = dataString.replace("\"", "&quot;")
    form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'testResults1' value = \"%s\">" % (dataString1)
    form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'testResults2' value = \"%s\">" % (dataString2)
    form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'testResults3' value = \"%s\">" % (dataString3)
    form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'testResults4' value = \"%s\">" % (dataString4) 

    form += "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'resultsToPrint' > \n"#value is determined by javascript:getDetails()
    form += "</form> \n"
    return form
```

I then submit the specific field based on which link was clicked. For example if I click link 1, then it will only send the field with dataString1. Basically the question boils down to this, **can I submit just certain fields in a form rather than the entire form based on user actions**

Comment: You could set all the inputs to *disabled* initially, then only enable (set `control.disabled = false`) the ones you want to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just a trivial example of how you might go about this. You can disable all the inputs by default, then just enable the ones you want just before submitting the form.

I've just submitted the form using its submit method, you might want to use AJAX or whatever. Also, you might want to attach listeners dynamically, or use event delegation (which would be my preferred design).

```
<script>

function doSend(el) {
  var form = document.forms['form0'];
  var controlName = el.getAttribute('data-sendName');
  form[controlName].disabled = false;
  form.submit();
}

</script>

<form id="form0">
  <input name="foo" value="foo" disabled>
  <input name="bar" value="bar" disabled>
</form>

<p onclick="doSend(this)" data-sendName="foo">Send foo</p>
<p onclick="doSend(this)" data-sendName="bar">Send bar</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, on the click event - just post your data with ajax:

```
$('#input1').on('click', function(){
    var value1 = $('#input1').val();
    $.post("test.php", {name: value1, time: "2pm"});
})
```

Comment: I am a beginner when it comes to web development. Could you walk me through what is going on here? Or could you point me to a resource on where I can learn more about what you are doing here?